# Performance Testing Windows/Desktop based Application

Tags: c#

We have a Windows based Client-Server Application where the Server is located in a Remote Location and it is being accessed from Clients located at another place, the Database used for this SQL Server.
  I would like to do a Performance Test of this Application how can I do that ? Is there a tool available for the same ?
  Please suggest

Comment: I believe this is on-topic for SO. Performance testing is part of application development, even if some of the components reside on remote servers.

Answer (score 1):

Let's talk about your requirements:  You note a performance test, what are your core critical measures of success or failure?   Do you have a load profile for your application with the business functions, the number of users and their frequency of occurrence?   Typically log files or changes in records within the database can provide an objective measure of frequency of business actions.

The issue of requirements goes directly to your inquiry on performance.   Are you interested in the difference of network response time from location ***a*** to location ***b***, the time for the ***sql*** conversation to complete from a to b, or the end user response time at the same?   Is this to be measured under load, or only for a single instance at this distant location?   How are you factoring in the uncontrolled element of the complex network between the location of the remote client and the server, for this impacts test reproducibility to a very high degree?  Or, is it simply enough to take a 'sniffer' trace for a view of time to last byte of request to time to first/last byte of response for some number of samples over time?

Depending upon your requirements different tools are likely to be called for, from passive tools such as a protocol analyzer, to active test tools for network, for database transactions or even for driving the front end client.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a performance monitor on the server. Just add appropriate counters to it (SQLServer.Transactions, etc). Also you can save collected info to log-files. 
Check this link for details: [Understanding SQL Performance Counters](http://www.extremeexperts.com/sql/articles/sqlcounters.aspx)

Also you can integrate PerfCounters into your app. Read this: [Performance Counters in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8f5kw2e.aspx)

Here is simple example how you can add PerfCounters to your app:

```
    string category = "My Category", counter = "My Counter";

if (!PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists(category))
{
    var ccd = new CounterCreationData(counter, "", PerformanceCounterType.NumberOfItems32);
    var ccdcol = new CounterCreationDataCollection() { ccd };

    PerformanceCounterCategory.Create(category, "", PerformanceCounterCategoryType.SingleInstance, ccdcol);
}
//else
//    PerformanceCounterCategory.Delete(category);

var pc = new PerformanceCounter(category, counter, false) { MachineName = ".", RawValue = 0 };

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    pc.RawValue = i;
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I like [HP's Performace Center](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/software/software-product.html?compURI=tcm:245-937011&pageTitle=performance-center) for this.
I'm sure there are [others](http://www.opensourcetesting.org/performance.php)